# Identification: which font is used by the Estonian soccer team?

Tags: font-identification

I watched the soccer game NL-EST a few months ago and kept being distracted by the font on the Estonian players' shirts. Very nice.

I tried identifying the font through WhatTheFont, but didn't succeed.

[image: Font sample]

It could of course be a custom-made font, just for those shirts.

Comment: i think they not used any font, look like Photoshop or AI drawing

Answer (score 6):

This looks very much like this font is based on lettering by various Estonian artists in 1960-1970s which is very similar to the traditional Basque style.

You can see some relevant lettering samples here:

[image] [source](http://luc.devroye.org/fonts-44776.html)

[image] [source](http://luc.devroye.org/fonts-44772.html)

[image] [source](http://luc.devroye.org/fonts-44773.html)

but unfortunately I was unable to find any actual fonts based on these.

Comment: The second one is pretty close!

Comment: Heh :) I was checking out the image in the second link and I just thought I was reading it wrong, but then I realized it was Estonian. -- Estonian uses a whole lot of same/similar words as we do in Finnish, although the meaning of the words are different ...and my reading sucks.

Comment: This one, from the same site, also looks pretty similar: http://luc.devroye.org/MartAnderson-Sula-2005.jpg

Comment: Mart Anderson currently occupies the position of art director at DDB Eesti, if you really need any collaboration I think you can contact him via LinkedIn

Comment: I must say second one is not close compare the letter L, you can justify, but the 3rd one is close

Comment: I'm only thinking about using such a font as header font on my website. So collaboration is not what I'm after, a (web)font will be enough :-)

Comment: I may suggest a roughly similar font, P22 Yule Heavy: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ihof/p22-yule/

Answer (score 0):

the font is Hanse by Mart Anderson

Comment: Hi Jåtså, welcome to GDSE. Thank you for your answer. While it might be correct, we typically look for longer answers. Could you [edit] your answer and improve it with a link to an official site about it, and maybe a visual sample to verify? Thanks so much for your time and effort. Feel free to browse the site, post more answers or maybe a question of your own, and upvote quality content when you see it.

Comment: In the discussion on the first answer, Mart Anderson was already mentioned. I googled his work and thought his "sula" font came pretty close: http://luc.devroye.org/MartAnderson-Sula-2005.jpg. Close, but not 100%. When googling for "Hanse" I don't find a good descriptive page, basically only some poster, https://www.pinterest.com/pin/313211349073984051/ , but I'm not sure that's the font you mean and whether is is from Mart Anderson. The font shown there *does* have some characteristics of the font used by the soccer team.